# Unable to prepare route [wave/presence-channel-users] for serialization. Another route has already been assigned name [wave.presence-chan nel-users]

Tags: laravel, server-sent-events, laravel-echo

i am trying to implement Server-sent events in a laravel app using qruto/laravel-wave but nothing happens when I dispatch an event. I checked the console and it shows a 500 error p://127.0.0.1:8000/wave 500 (Internal Server Error)

I tried to run `php artisan route:cache` but it return an error: Unable to prepare route [wave/presence-channel-users] for serialization. Another route has already been assigned name [wave.presence-chan nel-users].

Answer (score 1):

The exception `Unable to prepare route [wave/presence-channel-users] for serialization. Another route has already been assigned name [wave.presence-chan nel-users]` gets triggered when more than one route within your route file(s) have the same name, e.g.:

```php
Route::as('wave.')->prefix('wave')->group(function () {
    Route::get('presence-channel-users', [SomeController::class, 'action'])->name('presence-chan nel-users');
});
Route::get('wave/presence-channel-users', [SomeController::class, 'action'])->name('wave.presence-chan nel-users');
```

In this example there's 2 routes with the same name. When trying to cache this, it will throw given exception. This can simply be resolved by changing the names of the non-unique routes and providing unique names for each.

In the case of using the routes of a package, check if you haven't declared routes already declared by the route. If so, see if you can disable the vendor routes, or give your custom route a unique name. In the case the double routes are defined within the package, report it to the package developer, and, again, see if you can disable the vendor routes as temporary fix.